# Is it possible to hook the API call that puts text on Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, api

There's a program called [PPStream](http://www.pps.tv/) which is currently only available in Chinese, it allows for access to a myriad of ad-supported movies and TV series. The problems is that it is in Chinese and menus are indecipherable.

Is it possible to hook into the part of Mac OS's API that puts text on the screen so that it routes it through a wordlist first, translating the text into English? Would the API hook be able to differentiate the different applications calling the API?

I have no experience at all with Mac APIs, just pondering on if this is worth pursuing or not.

Thanks.

**Edit**: The reason I would like to do this at API level is that I need to dynamically dispatch HTTP queries with a list of strings to be translated (movie titles Chinese -> English), and the edit-the-i18n-file approach wouldn't do. Any other suggestions?

---

Answer (score 2):

I haven't downloaded, installed or run PPStream myself so I'm speaking "out of my rear end" in a sense, but there are a number of ways to localize an app.  But you really need to have access to the raw, uncompiled code and project to do it correctly.

The three most likely ways the string resources are saved are these:

1)

The app may have a strings file from which it fetches the strings to be displayed in the interface.

You *may* be able to make a copy of this strings file and set it to English or whatever language you choose.

2)

The strings may be baked into the code itself.  This is generally a NO NO for commercial grade MacOS & iOS apps, but lazy and/or inexperienced developers can do this especially if they don't think their app will ever be used in other languages.

3)

The most likely set up is that there will be a folder hidden in the application package, inside the "Resources" folder, that has named like "en.lproj" or "English.lproj" or "de.lproj" or "zh_CN.lproj" or "zh_TW.lproj" (these last two are especially likely if this is only in Chinese).

Inside those folders will be localized XIB (or older NIB) files. And if you make a copy of this folder and then modify the newly made copy to add your new language.

Options 1 & 3 are ones you might be able to copy and then modify, but then again it might not work (especially these days when there's code & app signing).  I've never tried this without an accompanying project, so if you have success, you should comment your question and/or this answer and let us know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. However, I really need to find out what strings are written in the interface, as many of them are movie titles which are fetched from an online service (see edit above).

Comment: Movie titles fetched from an online service?  ugh.  Either get a copy of the source code, if you can convince them to give (or sell) it to you, or you'll have to re-implement this all yourself.  The only possible way around this might be to write a proxy but that would likely be as much work as you just re-doing it all as a brand new app.